# is it possible to retrieve the xml nodes path dynamically in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert an attribute in every xml node. As xml is changed every time some developer do a change so I want to retrieve xml node path dynamically first and then insert the attribute in it. Any idea how can I have a dynamic path of an xml instead of passing a absolute path.

I want to have the following piece of code in t-sql..As i want to perform the same thing in SQL instead of any .net or other applications

```
 XElement loadedXML = XElement.Load("test.xml"); 

 //filter all nodes 
 XElement procXML; 
 procXML = new XElement("Tree", 
  from el in loadedXML.Descendants("Node") 
  where (string)el.Attribute("ItemGUID") == currentNodeGUID 
  select el);
```

something like this in sql